# Missing mapping configuration, classes mapped in profile

Tags: c#, automapper

The profile:

```
public class StudentProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Student, StudentIndexModel>();
    }
}
```

And the line it breaks on:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Breaks here
    var students = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<StudentIndexModel>>(db.Students.ToList());

    return View(students);
}
```

I'm getting an unsupported mapping exception when it gets records from the database. No exception when there are no records returned (the table has no records)

**Error**

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types:
>   Student -> StudentIndexModel
>   ContosoUniversity.Models.Student -> ContosoUniversity.ViewModels.StudentIndexModel
>
> Destination path:
>   IEnumerable`1[0]

The student class:

```
public class Student : Entity
{
    public Student() { }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Forenames { get; set; }

    public DateTime EnrolmentDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Enrolment> Enrolments { get; set; }
}
```

And the StudentIndexModel class:

```
public class StudentIndexModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Forenames { get; set; }

    public DateTime EnrolmentDate { get; set; }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it again, I find the answer to my own question 2 seconds later.

I added this to the Global.asax:

```
AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
```

Where `AutomapperConfiguration` has the `Mapper.Initialize()` method